# How to run spring scheduled task using executable jar

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I want to develop a stand alone application which will perform some task on schedule. I am using spring @scheduled and taskscheduler to achieve this. I can't use spring boot as it needs spring 4.* and my maven project has dependencies on other projects that use spring 3. 
Here is my code ([reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html)):

Pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.pdp.ci</groupId>
    <artifactId>ci</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>file-requester</artifactId>
<name>file-requester</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pdp.ci</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-requester</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin> 
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
<executions> 
  <execution> 
    <phase>install</phase> 
      <goals> 
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> 
      </goals> 
      <configuration> 
         <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory> 
      </configuration> 
    </execution> 
  </executions> 
</plugin> 
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Component class containing scheduled method:

```
package com.ci.ias;

@Component
public class CustomRequester{

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=2000)
    public void processFiles(){
        logger.info("Process started");
        //task logic
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.ci.ias")
public class Requester implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }

}
```

I am able to build a jar. But unable to run as there is no 'main' method. How to run this scheduler using command line? I am a novice to this. Can anybody explain how does this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have spring-boot jar (seems likes your parent jar is contains dependencies of spring-boot)

**Spring-boot :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);


    }

}
```

**java -jar yourjar.jar**

Or just create a main method and call that class

```
public class AppMain {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "resource" })
    public static void main(String args[]){
        AbstractApplicationContext  context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Requester.class);
    }

}
```

Then you can add this main class in your manifest

**manifest.mf**

```html
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.MainClass
Class-Path: anyjarsneededtorunapp.jar
```

Call **java -jar yourjar.jar**